# jqgrid: how to programmatically serialize current form?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

how do you programmatically serialize the current data in the jqgrid form?

like $form.serialize(); and get back an array of json objects for each row?

`serializeRowData` seems to only fire when it is called by jqgrid not the user.

there seems to be no documentation on how to do this programmatically without relying on some callback hookups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand you correctly, but jqGrid form use internally `<form>` element with elements which have `name` attribute the same like `name` column of `colModel`. Thus you really can use `$form.serialize()` or `$form.serializeArray()` to get the data from Add/Edit form. You will don't get of cause more sophisticated data, for example in case of usage [edittype: "custom"](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#custom).